# Java 7 DateFormat to parse UTC date to Local Date

Tags: java, java-7, simpledateformat, date-format, date

Could you please let me know what should be the JDK 7 date format to parse the date 2019-06-18T19:04:30.515 UTC and change it to local date time?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] showing what you've tried so far? Do you want the result in the system time zone, or some other time zone?

Comment: First I want the Datformat to parse the date. Didn't find any format to include UTC timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find an interesting article about this subject:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

The explanation of the patterns can be found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

This makes me suggest "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS z" as pattern. I hope it helps you.

Comment: While `SimpleDateFormat` is built in with Java 7, it is also notoriously troublesome. The other and perhaps better option is the ThreeTen Backport library as explained in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

For Java 6 & 7, you can use the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project to bring most of the modern *java.time* functionality to Java 6 and Java 7. This means you can avoid using the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat` (replaced by `DateTimeFormatter`).

> parse the date 2019-06-18T19:04:30.515 UTC

First we manipulate your input string to fully comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). We replace that SPACE and “UTC” with a `Z`, pronounced “Zulu”.

```
String input = "2019-06-18T19:04:30.515 UTC".replace( " UTC" , "Z" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

> and change it to local date time?

To adjust to another time zone from UTC, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;  // Or "Europe/Berlin" etc. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

To generate a string representing that date-time value localized for the user’s human language and cultural norms, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`.